# How to avoid specialization after instantiation error?

Tags: c++, templates, nested-class

Here is the simplified problem.

```
template <class T>
std::string name(const T&);  // This is the template 
                             // I want to explicitly specialize.

class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
    };

    class Container : public ::Container<Inner> // This causes also an implicit
                                                // specialization of f::name
    {
    };
};
```

How can I specialize

```
template <class T>
std::string name(const T&);
```

for `Outer::Inner` ?

I cannot declare the explicit specialization in three places I considered:

```
template <class T>
std::string name(const T&); 

// 1. Here I cannot forward declare a nested class

class Outer
{
    class Inner
    {
    };

    // 2. Here I get error: explicit specialization
    //    in non-namespace scope 'class Outer'

    class Container : public ::Container<Inner>
    {
    };
};

// 3. Here I get error: specialization of '...' after instantiation
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this article](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm). You might be better off just writing a `name` function for the specific type you want to "specialize" for:

```
std::string name(const Outer::Inner&);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now that I see it I am amazed at what was I thinking. Just an overload would do, right? I will look at the article also!

Comment: Just one more thing. Where do I declare the overload? It seems that the problem remains. There is no place, for the same reason as the template case.

Comment: You can declare it wherever it is needed, and define it in a .cpp, just like any other function. You could have dedicated .h and .cpp files for it if it is needed in many places (you can also use `inline` to put the definition in the .h)